# Very weird browser behavior with BMP image

Tags: javascript, css, dom, bitmap

I am tasked with developing a browser-based UI for an AI application. I am attempting to include a .bmp format image and attach it to the DOM. When I do so, the styles are logged with blank strings. We chose a .bmp image format because the image must not be compressed. This is odd behavior that I have never encountered before.

My code (I will refactor it later; this is just a prototype for now):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .outer{
            width:500px;
            position:relative;
        }

        #container{
            background:transparent;
            width:500px;
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            z-index:5;
        }

        .image{
            width:500px;
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@7.0.3/konva.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        const outerContainer = document.querySelector('.outer');
        const canvas = document.querySelector('#container');
        const image = new Image();

        let kContainerWidth;
        let kContainerHeight;

        image.onload = () => {
           

            // image.width = '500px';
            // console.log('image width:', image.style.width);
            // console.log('image height: ', image.style.height);


            image.className = 'image';

            // outerContainer.style.height = `${image.style.height}px`;
            // canvas.style.height = `${image.style.height}px`;

            // kContainerWidth = 500;
            // kContainerHeight = image.style.height;

            outerContainer.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend',image);
            
            // console.log('image width:', image.style.width);
            // console.log('image height: ', image.style.height);
            console.log(image.style);
            // konvaInit();

        }

        image.src = './card-demo.bmp';


        function konvaInit(){

            const stage = new Konva.Stage({
            container: '#container', 
            width: kContainerWidth, 
            height: kContainerHeight
            });

            const layer = new Konva.Layer();

            // ========== Top Outer ================

            const topOuter = new Konva.Line({
                points: [0, 5, 500, 5], 
                stroke: 'blue', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return { 
                    x: this.absolutePosition().x, 
                    y: pos.y
                    }
                }, 
                hitStrokeWidth: 6,
                lineCap: 'round'
            });

            topOuter.on('mouseover', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'row-resize';
            });

            topOuter.on('dragstart', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'row-resize';
            });

            topOuter.on('mouseleave', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'default';
            });

            topOuter.on('dragend', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'default';
            });

            // =========== Top Inner ==============

            const topInner = new Konva.Line({
                points: [0, 15, 500, 15], 
                stroke: 'blue', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return { 
                    x: this.absolutePosition().x, 
                    y: pos.y
                    }
                }, 
                lineCap: 'round', 
                hitStrokeWidth: 6,
                dash: [20,5]
            });

            topInner.on('mouseover', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'row-resize';
            });

            topInner.on('dragstart', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'row-resize';
            });

            topInner.on('mouseleave', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'default';
            });

            topInner.on('dragend', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'default';
            });

            // ============== Bottom Outer ================

            const bottomOuter = new Konva.Line({
                points: [0, 295, 500, 295], 
                stroke: 'red', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                text: 'bottom outer',
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return {
                    x: this.absolutePosition().x, 
                    y: pos.y
                    }
                }, 
                lineCap: 'round'
            });

            const bottomInner = new Konva.Line({
                points: [0, 280, 500, 280], 
                stroke: 'red', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return {
                    x: this.absolutePosition().x, 
                    y: pos.y
                    }
                }, 
                lineCap: 'round', 
                dash: [20,5]
            });

            const leftOuter = new Konva.Line({
                points: [5, 0, 5, 300], 
                stroke: 'green', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return {
                    x: pos.x, 
                    y: this.absolutePosition().y
                    }
                }
            });

            const leftInner = new Konva.Line({
                points: [15, 0, 15, 300], 
                stroke: 'green', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return {
                    x: pos.x, 
                    y: this.absolutePosition().y
                    }
                }, 
                dash: [20,5]
            });

            const rightOuter = new Konva.Line({
                points: [495, 0, 495, 300], 
                stroke: 'orange', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return {
                    x: pos.x, 
                    y: this.absolutePosition().y
                    }
                }
            });

            const rightInner = new Konva.Line({
                points: [485, 0, 485, 300], 
                stroke: 'orange', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return {
                    x: pos.x, 
                    y: this.absolutePosition().y
                    }
                }, 
                dash: [20,5]
            });



            // bottomOuter.on('dragmove', () => {

            //    if(
            //        (bottomOuter.absolutePosition().y + 250) <=
            //        topOuter.absolutePosition().y
            //    ){
            //         console.log('exceeding...');
            //         bottomOuter.draggable(false);
            //         bottomOuter.position({
            //             x:0, 
            //             y:0
            //         });
            //         bottomOuter.draggable(true);
            //    }
            // });

            layer.add(topOuter);
            layer.add(topInner);
            layer.add(bottomOuter);
            layer.add(bottomInner);
            layer.add(leftOuter);
            layer.add(leftInner);
            layer.add(rightOuter);
            layer.add(rightInner);
            stage.add(layer);

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I `console.log()` the image.style object, I get this:

```js
CSSStyleDeclaration {alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", alignmentBaseline: "", all: "", …}
alignContent: ""
alignItems: ""
alignSelf: ""
alignmentBaseline: ""
all: ""
animation: ""
animationDelay: ""
animationDirection: ""
animationDuration: ""
animationFillMode: ""
animationIterationCount: ""
animationName: ""
animationPlayState: ""
animationTimingFunction: ""
appearance: ""
ascentOverride: ""
aspectRatio: ""
backdropFilter: ""
backfaceVisibility: ""
background: ""
backgroundAttachment: ""
backgroundBlendMode: ""
backgroundClip: ""
backgroundColor: ""
backgroundImage: ""
backgroundOrigin: ""
backgroundPosition: ""
backgroundPositionX: ""
backgroundPositionY: ""
backgroundRepeat: ""
backgroundRepeatX: ""
backgroundRepeatY: ""
backgroundSize: ""
baselineShift: ""
blockSize: ""
border: ""
borderBlock: ""
borderBlockColor: ""
borderBlockEnd: ""
borderBlockEndColor: ""
borderBlockEndStyle: ""
borderBlockEndWidth: ""
borderBlockStart: ""
borderBlockStartColor: ""
borderBlockStartStyle: ""
borderBlockStartWidth: ""
borderBlockStyle: ""
borderBlockWidth: ""
borderBottom: ""
borderBottomColor: ""
borderBottomLeftRadius: ""
borderBottomRightRadius: ""
borderBottomStyle: ""
borderBottomWidth: ""
borderCollapse: ""
borderColor: ""
borderEndEndRadius: ""
borderEndStartRadius: ""
...
```

When I `console.log(image.style.width)` or `console.log(image.style.height)`, it does not log anything to the console, not even an empty string, `null`, or `undefined`.

What is causing this strange behavior?

Edit: Wanted to also mention I am using Google Chrome on MacOS

Comment: Please post a working code snippet. The bmp path you provided is relative, so the image won't load anyway. Also, I'm guessing everything after `image.src = './card-demo.bmp';` can be removed from your post as it does not seem to be directly related to your issue.

Comment: You set the width of the image in a class but I can't see anywhere where the image.style is set so it just is empty, never been set when you console.log it. If you could get rid of code that isn't related to the problem as @chiliNUT suggests it would be easier to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the image.style.width (and height) are being logged but nowhere have they been set.

Assuming it is a requirement that they be set (500px is indicated in the code) then onload of the image we can do this:

```
image.onload = () => {
    const imageWidth = image.width;
    const imageHeight = image.height;
    console.log('natural width of image: ', imageWidth);
    console.log('natural height of image: ', imageHeight);
    
   //the next line is assumed what is required from the code in the question
     image.style.width = '500px';
     console.log('image.style.width:', image.style.width);
     image.style.height = (500 * imageHeight / imageWidth) + 'px'; //calculate height so in same aspect ratio as original image
     console.log('image.style.height: ', image.style.height);
```

Here's all the code with that change. Looking at the console log the width and height style are now set as wanted. (Note, the image used for this demo was originally bmp but imgur has given it png type - it will work if you put your bmp file as the src)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        .outer{
            width:500px;
            position:relative;
        }

        #container{
            background:transparent;
            width:500px;
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
            z-index:5;
        }

        .image{
            width:500px;
            position:absolute;
            left:0;
            top:0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="outer">
        <div id="container"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@7.0.3/konva.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        const outerContainer = document.querySelector('.outer');
        const canvas = document.querySelector('#container');
        const image = new Image();

        let kContainerWidth;
        let kContainerHeight;

        image.onload = () => {
            const imageWidth = image.width;
            const imageHeight = image.height;
            console.log('natural width of image: ', imageWidth);
            console.log('natural height of image: ', imageHeight);
            
           //the next line is assumed what is required from the code in the question
             image.style.width = '500px';
             console.log('image.style.width:', image.style.width);
             image.style.height = (500 * imageHeight / imageWidth) + 'px'; //calculate height so in same aspect ratio as original image
             console.log('image.style.height: ', image.style.height);


            image.className = 'image';

            // outerContainer.style.height = `${image.style.height}px`;
            // canvas.style.height = `${image.style.height}px`;

            // kContainerWidth = 500;
            // kContainerHeight = image.style.height;

            outerContainer.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend',image);
            
            // console.log('image width:', image.style.width);
            // console.log('image height: ', image.style.height);
            console.log(image.style);
            // konvaInit();

        }

        image.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLAWw.png';
        //ADDED FOR TEST
        image.src = 'https://ahweb.org.uk/sample_640×426.bmp';


        function konvaInit(){

            const stage = new Konva.Stage({
            container: '#container', 
            width: kContainerWidth, 
            height: kContainerHeight
            });

            const layer = new Konva.Layer();

            // ========== Top Outer ================

            const topOuter = new Konva.Line({
                points: [0, 5, 500, 5], 
                stroke: 'blue', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return { 
                    x: this.absolutePosition().x, 
                    y: pos.y
                    }
                }, 
                hitStrokeWidth: 6,
                lineCap: 'round'
            });

            topOuter.on('mouseover', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'row-resize';
            });

            topOuter.on('dragstart', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'row-resize';
            });

            topOuter.on('mouseleave', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'default';
            });

            topOuter.on('dragend', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'default';
            });

            // =========== Top Inner ==============

            const topInner = new Konva.Line({
                points: [0, 15, 500, 15], 
                stroke: 'blue', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return { 
                    x: this.absolutePosition().x, 
                    y: pos.y
                    }
                }, 
                lineCap: 'round', 
                hitStrokeWidth: 6,
                dash: [20,5]
            });

            topInner.on('mouseover', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'row-resize';
            });

            topInner.on('dragstart', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'row-resize';
            });

            topInner.on('mouseleave', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'default';
            });

            topInner.on('dragend', () => {
                stage.container().style.cursor = 'default';
            });

            // ============== Bottom Outer ================

            const bottomOuter = new Konva.Line({
                points: [0, 295, 500, 295], 
                stroke: 'red', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                text: 'bottom outer',
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return {
                    x: this.absolutePosition().x, 
                    y: pos.y
                    }
                }, 
                lineCap: 'round'
            });

            const bottomInner = new Konva.Line({
                points: [0, 280, 500, 280], 
                stroke: 'red', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return {
                    x: this.absolutePosition().x, 
                    y: pos.y
                    }
                }, 
                lineCap: 'round', 
                dash: [20,5]
            });

            const leftOuter = new Konva.Line({
                points: [5, 0, 5, 300], 
                stroke: 'green', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return {
                    x: pos.x, 
                    y: this.absolutePosition().y
                    }
                }
            });

            const leftInner = new Konva.Line({
                points: [15, 0, 15, 300], 
                stroke: 'green', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return {
                    x: pos.x, 
                    y: this.absolutePosition().y
                    }
                }, 
                dash: [20,5]
            });

            const rightOuter = new Konva.Line({
                points: [495, 0, 495, 300], 
                stroke: 'orange', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return {
                    x: pos.x, 
                    y: this.absolutePosition().y
                    }
                }
            });

            const rightInner = new Konva.Line({
                points: [485, 0, 485, 300], 
                stroke: 'orange', 
                strokeWidth: 2, 
                draggable: true, 
                dragBoundFunc(pos){
                    return {
                    x: pos.x, 
                    y: this.absolutePosition().y
                    }
                }, 
                dash: [20,5]
            });



            // bottomOuter.on('dragmove', () => {

            //    if(
            //        (bottomOuter.absolutePosition().y + 250) <=
            //        topOuter.absolutePosition().y
            //    ){
            //         console.log('exceeding...');
            //         bottomOuter.draggable(false);
            //         bottomOuter.position({
            //             x:0, 
            //             y:0
            //         });
            //         bottomOuter.draggable(true);
            //    }
            // });

            layer.add(topOuter);
            layer.add(topInner);
            layer.add(bottomOuter);
            layer.add(bottomInner);
            layer.add(leftOuter);
            layer.add(leftInner);
            layer.add(rightOuter);
            layer.add(rightInner);
            stage.add(layer);

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, the formula is helpful for calculating the height. Although, I thought with CSS, the browser sets defaults for all styles unless otherwise specified. Am I wrong?

Comment: Styles aren’t set unless you set them. I don’t think any are though I stand to be corrected,  anyway width and height aren’t set at least.